# NoClassDefFoundError with Apache CXF, Wildfly and Java 1.7

Tags: web-services, maven, jakarta-ee, jboss, cxf

I know there are lots of question about that, but the problem is that, I searched and googled everything around it, but nothing found that could help me.

I try to implement SOAP based web service client using Apache CXF/Wildfly 8x/Java 1.7/Maven 3+/Eclipse.

I generate proxy classes successfully, implemented ws-security options, add keystore and trustore, but found a very strange problem.

```
[io.undertow.request] (default task-18) UT005023: Exception handling request to /service/DummyServiceCaller: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/frontend/ClientProxy
    at com.ddrc.service.Service.core.config.ServiceManager.beforeExecute(ServiceManager.java:17) [:]
    at com.ddrc.service.service.core.ServiceManager.executeService(ServiceServiceManager.java:36) [:]
    at com.ddrc.service.DummyServiceCaller.doGet(DummyServiceCaller.java:37) [:]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:790) [jboss-servlet-api_3.1_spec-1.0.0.Final.jar:1.0.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletHandler.handleRequest(ServletHandler.java:85) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:61) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:56) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:45) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:63) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:58) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:70) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.SecurityInitialHandler.handleRequest(SecurityInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.jrHandle(ServletInitialHandler.java) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at org.zeroturnaround.javarebel.integration.servlet.undertow.cbp.ServletInitialHandlerCBP.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandlerCBP.java:100) [undertow-servlet-jr-plugin-6.2.7.jar:]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:261) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:247) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:76) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:166) [undertow-servlet-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:197) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:759) [undertow-core-1.1.0.Final.jar:1.1.0.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145) [jrebel-bootstrap-39173be574c0f43be80eb922241c6711.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615) [jrebel-bootstrap-39173be574c0f43be80eb922241c6711.jar:1.7.0_75]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [jrebel-bootstrap-39173be574c0f43be80eb922241c6711.jar:1.7.0_75]
```

As i read about that exception, it means that,

> This is caused when there is a class file that your code depends on
>   and it is present at compile time but not found at runtime. Look for
>   differences in your build time and runtime classpaths.

Source [stackoverflow explanation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34413/why-am-i-getting-a-noclassdeffounderror-in-java)

1. Of course, I cleaned and rebuild project, restart eclipse but no reaction.
2. Then I made a simple small project and copied the code there, still same problem.
3. Then I searched the class in maven repos, found it, opened jar and found the class too.
4. Then I created runnable jar and copied in my mates PC, checked there and same problem.
5. Searched a lot but nothing special found.
6. The only interesting article I found was here [CXF](http://cxf.apache.org/docs/30-migration-guide.html) but could not understand.

> ClientProxy.getClient(proxy) is no longer needed for most use cases. 
>   The client proxy instances now implement the Client API directly.   A
>   direct cast to Client should work.

I do not even know how to start fixing this, how to debug this. Here is the code I wrote.

```
private void adjustServiceConfiguration(Object port, String address) throws IOException {
        org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client client = ClientProxy.getClient(port);
        HTTPConduit http = (HTTPConduit) client.getConduit();
        HTTPClientPolicy httpClientPolicy = new HTTPClientPolicy();
        httpClientPolicy.setConnectionTimeout(/* uccConnectionTimeout.value() */6 * 1000);
        httpClientPolicy.setReceiveTimeout(/* uccTimeout.value() */7 * 1000);
        http.setClient(httpClientPolicy);

        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put(BindingProvider.ENDPOINT_ADDRESS_PROPERTY, address);
        ((BindingProvider) port).getRequestContext().put("set-jaxb-validation-event-handler", "false");

        Map<String, Object> outProps = new HashMap<>();
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Timestamp Signature Encrypt");//
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, "PasswordDigest");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.USER, "ucc-agent");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIGNATURE_USER, "ucc-agent");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, "com.ddrc.service.service.ws.KeyStorePasswordsCallback");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENCRYPTION_USER, "ucc");

        if (encryptionProps == null || signProps == null) {
            try {
                encryptionProps = new Properties();
                signProps = new Properties();
                try (FileInputStream fis1 = new FileInputStream(
                        uccEncryptionPropFile);
                        FileInputStream fis2 = new FileInputStream(
                                uccSignaturePropFile);) {
                    encryptionProps.load(fis1);
                    signProps.load(fis2);
                }
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                throw ex;
                // log.error("Error occurred during UCC WS-Security configuration file lookup",
                // ex);
            }
        }

        outProps.put("encryptionProps", encryptionProps);
        outProps.put("signProps", signProps);
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ENC_PROP_REF_ID, "encryptionProps");
        outProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_REF_ID, "signProps");

        Map<String, Object> inProps = new HashMap<>();
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ACTION, "Timestamp Signature Encrypt");
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PASSWORD_TYPE, "PasswordText");
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.PW_CALLBACK_CLASS, "com.ddrc.service.service.ws.KeyStorePasswordsCallback");
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.ALLOW_RSA15_KEY_TRANSPORT_ALGORITHM, "true");

        inProps.put("signProps", signProps);
        inProps.put("encryptionProps", encryptionProps);
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.DEC_PROP_REF_ID, "signProps");
        inProps.put(WSHandlerConstants.SIG_PROP_REF_ID, "encryptionProps");

        client.getInInterceptors().add(new WSS4JInInterceptor(inProps));
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new WSS4JOutInterceptor(outProps));
        client.getInInterceptors().add(new LoggingInInterceptor());
        client.getOutInterceptors().add(new LoggingOutInterceptor());
    }
```

The problem is in `ClientProxy` class

Here is an error from small project.

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/cxf/common/i18n/UncheckedException
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:800)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:449)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:71)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:361)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    at ge.test.Run.main(Run.java:16)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.cxf.common.i18n.UncheckedException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358)
    ... 13 more
```

and the whole class :)

```
package ge.test;

import org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client;
import org.apache.cxf.frontend.ClientProxy;

public class Run {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Client c = ClientProxy.getClient(null);
    }

}
```

Comment: Include the pom.xml in the question!

Comment: OK. I figure out that, my ear could not see correct classloader, so when i manually added lib folder inside ear file and copied all jar in folder everything worked. I have the only question now. How can i configure jboss to automatically read cxf libraries without copying them in the lib folder?

Comment: A few years later your reference to "A direct cast to Client should work" really saved me.  I was in a classloader conflict hell, digging myself deeper and deeper with every new dependency I thought I needed.  Instead of calling ClientProxy.getClient(proxy), casting my proxy to (org.apache.cxf.endpoint.Client) did the trick.  Thank you!